# Вывести имена в подкатегории, которая в подкатегории с главной категории php, sql

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, foreach

Есть на сайте категория, в ней подкатегория и в этой подкатегории её подкатегория(надеюсь понятно).
[image: БД]

[image: Сайт]

Главная категория Автопринадлежности, при наведении на неё нужно вывести все её подкатегории(допустим Автоаксессуары) и у этой подкатегории её подкатегории(все остальные товары в first_name). Я их разделил по столбцам third_id, second_id, first_id и пытаюсь их вывести по этим столбцам сравнивая их номера. Но при наводке на главную категорию(Автопринадлежности)мне выводит только Автоаксессуары, а там должно быть 9 подкатегорий, но выводится одна и в это подкатегории выводится тоже только одна её подкатегория(Авто салфетки). Уже много что перепробовал, не получается. Если в sql написать SELECT DISTINCT `first_name` FROM `category` WHERE `third_id` = 0 and `second_id` = 0 то выведет всё правильно, но он же выведет только которые равны 0, а там у всех разные цифры( 0 и 1 допустим, 0 и 2).

```
<ul id="menu-list" class="dropdown-menu">

                            <?php
                                $elems1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT `third_name` FROM `category`");
                                foreach ($elems1 as $elem1) { ?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <span class="toggle-child"><i class="fa fa-plus plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus minus"></i></span>
                                        <a href="#" class="parent-link dropdown-img"><?=$elem1['third_name']?><i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow"></i></a> <!-- Категория 3 -->

                                    <div class="ns-dd dropdown-menu-simple nsmenu-type-category-simple">
                                        <div class="dropdown-inner">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled nsmenu-haschild">
                                            <?php 
                                                $elems2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT `second_name` FROM `category` WHERE `second_id` = `first_id`");
                                                foreach ($elems2 as $elem2) 
                                                { ?>
                                                <li class="nsmenu-issubchild">
                                                    <a href="#"><?=$elem2['second_name']?><i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow"></i></a> <!-- Категория 2 -->
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled nsmenu-ischild nsmenu-ischild-simple">
                                                            <?php 
                                                            $elems3 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT `first_name` FROM `category` WHERE `third_id` = `second_id` and `second_id` = `first_id`");
                                                            foreach ($elems3 as $elem3 ) { ?>    
                                                            <li class=""><a href="#"><?=$elem3['first_name']?></a></li> <!-- Категория 1 -->
                                                            <?php } ?>
                                                        </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если по правильному, то у вас структура хранения данных не очень верная, т.к. есть распространенный патер `material path`, который решает подобные проблемы и зачастую используется при построении того же каталога с неопределенной глубиной, советую взглянуть на него, можно [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/354694/).

Если в вкратце, то у вас будет список категорий как он есть и будет единственное поле `parent_id`, в таком случае, получится обычное несбалансированное дерево.

В такой структуре, чтобы выбрать верхний уровень (главные категории) в выбираете все записи, у которых `parent_id=null`, далее, выбираете категории второго уровня, это все те записи, у которых `parent_id={идентификатор категории с первого уровня, там где был null}` и т.д.

В таком случае, все можно решить одним запросом.